# How to match numbers that lie outside the range

Tags: perl

I am trying to print values of range from @arr3 which are same and lie outside the range from @arr4 (not included in range of arr4) but I am not getting the desired output. Please suggest me the modifications in the following code to get the output as 1,2,8,13 (without repeating the values if any)

File 1: result

```
1..5   
5..10
10..15
```

File 2: annotation

```
3..7
9..12
14..17
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open($inp1, "<result")     or die "not found";
open($inp2, "<annotation") or die "not found";

my @arr3 = <$inp1>;
my @arr4 = <$inp2>;

foreach my $line1 (@arr4) {
  foreach my $line2 (@arr3) {

    my ($from1, $to1) = split(/\.\./, $line1);
    my ($from2, $to2) = split(/\.\./, $line2);

    for (my $i = $from1 ; $i <= $to1 ; $i++) {
      for (my $j = $from2 ; $j <= $to2 ; $j++) {

        $res = grep(/$i/, @result);    #to avoid repetition

        if ($i != $j && $res == 0) {

          print "$i \n";

          push(@result, $i);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
open (my $inp1,"<result.txt") or die "not found";
open (my $inp2,"<annotation.txt") or die "not found";

my @result;
my @annotation;

foreach my $line2 (<$inp2>) {
    my ($from2,$to2)=split(/\.\./,$line2);
    @annotation = (@annotation, $from2..$to2);
}
print join(",",@annotation),"\n";
my %in_range = map {$_=> 1} @annotation;

foreach my $line1 (<$inp1>) {
    my ($from1,$to1)=split(/\.\./,$line1);
    @result = (@result, $from1..$to1);
}

print join(",",@result),"\n";
my %tmp_hash = map {$_=> 1} @result;
my @unique = sort {$a <=> $b} keys %tmp_hash;
print join(",",@unique),"\n";

my @out_of_range = grep {!$in_range{$_}} @unique;
print join(",",@out_of_range),"\n";
```

The `print` statements are temporary, of course, to help show what's going on when you run this.  The basic idea is you use one hash to eliminate duplicate numbers in your "result", and another hash to indicate which ones are in the "annotations".

If you used pattern-matching rather than `split` then I think it would be a little easier to make this ignore extra lines of input that aren't ranges of numbers, in case you ever have input files with a few "extra" lines that you need to skip over.

Answer (score 1):

If the contents of the files is under your control, you can make use of `eval` for parsing them. On the other hand, if there might be something else than what you specified, the following is dangerous to use.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $inc, '<', 'result';
open my $exc, '<', 'annotation';

my (%include, %exclude, @result);
while (<$inc>) { $include{$_} = 1 for eval $_ }
while (<$exc>) { $exclude{$_} = 1 for eval $_ }

for (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %include) {
    push @result, $_ unless $exclude{$_}
}
print Dumper \@result;
```

Returns:

```
$VAR1 = [ 1, 2, 8, 13 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

The only major tool you need is a `%seen` style hash as represented in [perlfaq4 - How can I remove duplicate elements from a list or array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array%3f)

The following opens filehandles to string references, but obviously these could be replaced with the appropriate file names:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my %seen;

open my $fh_fltr, '<', \ "3..7\n9..12\n14..17\n";
while (<$fh_fltr>) {
    my ($from, $to) = split /\.{2}/;
    $seen{$_}++ for $from .. $to;
}

my @result;

open my $fh_src, '<', \ "1..5\n5..10\n10..15\n";
while (<$fh_src>) {
    my ($from, $to) = split /\.{2}/;
    push @result, $_ for grep {!$seen{$_}++} $from .. $to;
}

print "@result\n";
```

Outputs:

```
1 2 8 13
```